# How to split numbers of letters in python

Tags: python

If I have a string like "MZA11LTE12DEP108N" which is a concatenation of letter groups and digit groups, how do I split them with a delimiter space character inbetween? in python

Comment: Are you trying to split the string into groups of digits and letters?

Comment: well i think you should use   Regex

Comment: Show what the result of splitting your example would be.

Answer (score 10):

Assuming I'm understanding you, [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) could work:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> s = "MZA11LTE12DEP108N"
>>> [''.join(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(s, str.isalpha)]
['MZA', '11', 'LTE', '12', 'DEP', '108', 'N']
>>> ' '.join(''.join(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(s, str.isalpha))
'MZA 11 LTE 12 DEP 108 N'
```

Answer (score 3):

Or a regex solution:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "MZA11LTE12DEP108N"
>>> re.sub('(?<=\d)(?!\d)|(?<!\d)(?=\d)', ' ', s)
'MZA 11 LTE 12 DEP 108 N'
```

More verbosely:

```
re.compile("""
    (?<=\d) # an empty string preceded by a digit
    (?!\d)  # followed by a non-digit
    |   # or
    (?<!\d) # an empty string preceded by a non-digit
    (?=\d)  # followed by a digit
""", re.VERBOSE).sub(' ', s)
```

Comment: Alternative with simpler regex using `findall`: `' '.join(re.findall('\d+|\D+', s))`

Answer (score 1):

well this is solution but it's so complicated :D , i've post it just as another solution for out of box LOL

```
counter=0
txt='MZA11LTE12DEP108N'
string= ' '
while counter<len(txt):
    figure=str(txt[counter])
    if figure.isdigit():
        if string[-1].isdigit():
           string +=figure
        else:
            string += " "+figure
    else:
        if figure.isalpha():
            if string[-1].isalpha():string+=figure
            else:string += " "+figure

    counter+=1
string = string.strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want to separate characters in a variable, and digits in another then stick both of them with a space between them then:

```
variable = "MZA11LTE12DEP108N"
varlist = list(variable)
num = len(varlist)
strings = ''
digits = ''
for i in range(num):
    if varlist[i].isalpha():
        strings += varlist[i]
    elif varlist[i].isdigit():
        digits += varlist[i]
variable = strings+' '+digits
```

Not sure if this is the best way.

Comment: well yours is separating strings from digit ,, i mean combining strings together and digits together ,,, i think values should be 'MZA 11 LTE 12 DEP 108 N'

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I thought the intention was to remove non-numerics *sigh* hence my previous incorrect answer.

```
In [473]: re.findall(r'(\D+|\d+)',"MZA11LTE12DEP108N")
Out[473]: ['MZA', '11', 'LTE', '12', 'DEP', '108', 'N']
```